# cannot replicate curl request from postman in console

Tags: curl, postman

I have an endpoint works in Postman, but I cannot get it to work via console. I tried to get the curl code from Postman but that is not working.

Here you can see that the request works in Postman and the curl code it gives me.
[image]

[image]

Here you can see me trying the curl code, but I get several errors.
[image]

I removed the part about the cookies, but I'm still getting errors.
[image]

I tried removing `--location` and moving the url to the end, which seems to get me a little farther:
[image]

Finally I tried using the `-d` parameter, but that does not seem to change anything:
[image]

I have 3 questions:

1. Why does `--location https://XXXXXXXXXXX` not work?
2. How am I supposed to send `grant_type` in the body if `--data-urlencode` and `-d` are not the correct way?
3. What is Postman doing correctly that I am not doing on console?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the key is the `Content-Type` header, which means my request body needs to be formatted as

```
"client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&scope=XXX&grant_type=XXX"
```

instead of the json way I was doing previously.